# Price filter using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a price filter from following table. Currently works with two mysql query first one create price range and second will create count by an ajax call.

[image]

Is there any other way to get both in single query.

Expected result:

```
300- 400 (2)
400- 500 (2)
500- 600 (2)
600- 620 (2)
```

Comment: How are you calculating the price ranges?

Comment: There are 6 id's but each range contains 2, how does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say this query returns your price range:

```
SELECT a, b FROM x WHERE ... blah blah blah
```

Now. If you want to count this is what i would do:

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT(y.a,'-',y.b) "range",
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item WHERE price BETWEEN y.a AND y.b) "total"
FROM 
     (SELECT a, b FROM x) AS y
```

I think it should work. I don't know if is the best way but give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table `price_range` with `low` and `high` columns:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(low, '-', high) as range,
    sum(price between low and high) as total
FROM price_range
CROSS JOIN item
```

If you don't have a table, but have a query instead, do similar to above, but with the query aliased:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(low, '-', high) as range,
    sum(price between low and high) as total
FROM (select low, high from some_table) as price_range
CROSS JOIN item
```